# understanding decode() and encode() unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I just can't get how the functions `decode()` and `encode()` work on python2.7

I tried the followings statement

```
>>> s = u'abcd'
>>> s.encode('utf8')
'abcd'
>>> s.encode('utf16')
'\xff\xfea\x00b\x00c\x00d\x00'
>>> s.encode('utf32')
'\xff\xfe\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00'
```

untill here, I think it's clear; `encode()` translate a unicode code in the corresponding utf-8/16/32 byte string.

But when I code:

```
>>> s.decode('utf8')
u'abcd'
>>> s.decode('utf16')
u'\u6261\u6463'
>>> s.decode('utf32')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_32.py", line 11, in decode
    return codecs.utf_32_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf32' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: codepoint not in range(0x110000)
```

why the meaning of `decode()` on a unicode type? Why does the first (with utf8) work instead the latters not? Is it because python internally stores unicode strings using utf-8?

One last thing:

```
>>> s2 = '≈'
>>> s2
'\xe2\x89\x88'
```

What happens under the hood? '≈' is not an ascii character, so does python convert it implicitly using the encoding `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returns?

Comment: Martijn's answer explains the situation.  It's worth noting that this confusion is cleared up in Python 3.  In Python 3, unicode objects don't have a `decode` method and bytes objects don't have an `encode` method, so you can't accidentally do the encoding/decoding in the wrong direction.

Comment: Can you please not keep expanding your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `decode` on a `unicode` string. Python helpfully first *encodes* the string using the default ASCII codec so that you have actual bytes *to* decode. You cannot decode Unicode data itself, it is *already* decoded.

That decoding then fails as the bytes are not valid UTF-32 data. The bytestring `'abcd'` is decodable as UTF-8, because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. Encoding to ASCII then decoding as UTF-8 produces the same information. Decoding as UTF-16 happened to work by chance; you provided 4 bytes with hex values 0x61, 0x62, 0x63 and 0x64 (the ASCII values for the characters `abcd`), and those bytes can be decoded as UTF-16 little endian for `\u6261` and `\u6463`. But there is no valid decoding for those 4 bytes in the UTF-32 encoding system.

If `s` had data in it that cannot be encoded to ASCII first, you'll get a `UnicodeEncodeError` exception; note the *Encode* in that name:

```
>>> u'åßç'.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

because the implicit encoding to a bytestring failed.

In Python 3, `unicode` objects have been renamed to `str`, and the `str.decode()` method has been removed from the type to prevent this kind of confusion. Only `str.encode()` remains. The Python `str` type has been replaced by the `bytes` type, which only has an `bytes.decode()` method.

Your second example shows that you are using the Python interpreter interactively in a terminal or console. Python received your input from the terminal as UTF-8 bytes and stored those bytes in a bytestring. Had you used a `unicode` literal, Python would have automatically decoded those bytes using the encoding declared for your terminal; you can introspect `sys.stdin.encoding` to see what Python detected:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> s = '≈'
>>> s
'\xe2\x89\x88'
>>> s = u'≈'
>>> s
u'\u2248'
>>> print s
≈
```

Vice-versa, when printing the `sys.stdout.encoding` codec is used to auto-encode Unicode strings to the codec used by your terminal, which then interprets those bytes again to display the right glyphs on your screen.

If you are not working in the Python interactive interpreter but are instead working with a Python source file, the codec to use is instead determined by the [PEP-263 *Python source code encodings declaration*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), as Python 2 otherwise defaults to decoding bytes as ASCII.

`sys.getfilesystemencoding()` has nothing to do with all this; it tells you what Python think your *file system metadata* is encoded with; e.g. the filenames in directories. The values is used when you use `unicode` paths for filesystem-related calls like `os.listdir()`.

Comment: Last part of the answer is pretty confusing to me: `s = '≈'` and then `'\xe2\x89\x88'` because Python received the char as an utf-8 char and I can't see it from `sys.stdin.encoding` which returns `utf-8`. Now I don't understand what you want to say if I had used `s = u'≈'`

Comment: @antox: `u'≈'.encode('utf8') == '\xe2\x89\x88'`. The UTF-8 encoding for `≈` is those 3 bytes.

Comment: so do you mean that `str` and `unicode` types store the values using the encoding returned by `sys.stdin.encoding`? in the same way?

Comment: @antox: no, `str` stored the bytes. `unicode` stores unicode, but you need to decode the bytes first. Python will use `sys.stdin.encoding` to do the latter.

Comment: @antox: your terminal will always send bytes, however.

Comment: one last thing; instead when printing the name s (`s = u'≈'`) implicitly it's like if bytes from `s.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)` are sent to the monitor and then displayed, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, `print` writes to `sys.stdout` which encodes `unicode` values automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69800/discussion-between-antox-and-martijn-pieters).