# Getting "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode" when decoding from windows-1252?

Tags: python

I have a file which [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) thinks is probably `windows1252`:

```
$ chardetect pub5.xml
pub5.xml: windows-1252 with confidence 0.73
```

When I try to read it in Python and then write it to a CSV file, I get errors:

```
str = row[r].decode('windows-1252').encode('utf8')
```

The error I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    csv_filename='output/studies.csv'
  File "parser.py", line 15, in parse_data_to_csv
    self._write_csv_file(csv_header, csv_filename, xml_files)
  File "parser.py", line 114, in _write_csv_file
    str = row[r].decode('windows-1252').encode('utf8')
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I don't understand why the `ascii` codec is needed to decode something out of `windows-1252`. Can anyone help?

The string that is failing is: `aa Mixéu 2002`. The same code works OK in the Python console:

```
str = 'aa Mixéu 2002'
str.decode('windows-1252').encode('utf8')
'aa Mix\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9u 2002'
```

I'm setting the value of `row[r]` using lxml, I don't know if that's relevant:

```
studies = root.findall('.//STUDY')
for study_wrapper in studies:
    row = {}
    row['study_name'] = study_wrapper.get('NAME')
```

Perhaps lxml is somehow setting it to ASCII?

**UPDATE**: Figured it out:

```
try:
  row[r] = row[r].encode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
  row[r] = row[r].decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

Seems that some incoming strings are in UTF8 and some are not - from the same file!

Comment: `print repr(row[r])` before you try and decode/encode ...

Comment: See [understanding decode() and encode() unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28201580)

Comment: `lxml` decodes input to Unicode for you, you don't need to decode yourself.

Comment: And you don't need to use chardet here either; XML documents state in their header what codec they are encoded to in the `<?xml ...?>` preamble, which is why `lxml` can decode the data automatically in the first place; if the preamble is missing, the default is to decode from UTF-8.

Comment: I'm punching re-open on this one. Anyway this guy's solution he added to end of question is running straight into disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect `isinstance(row[r],unicode) == True`

this makes the first `decode` break , since `decode` expects a bytestring and returns unicode ... if it already has unicode it tries to encode it with the default terminal encoding (which is usually ascii)

try: `row[r].encode("utf-8")`

Comment: Thanks, this set me on the right path (see my update). I hadn't tried this before since it made the script break elsewhere. Seems some incoming strings are UTF8 and some not.

Comment: well you are closer... I think you dont quite have it but if it works it works ;)